# Kubernetes: Create an Ingress for Kafka

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have Confluent Kafka 5.3.1 pods running with Zookeeper with SSL on AWS.
How can I make the Ingress work? I want to give access to an external user, to my Kafka topic. This should work as a Layer-4 ingress as it is on port 9092~3.

I am trying to find some documentation online.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked?

Answer (score 1):

Ingress is only an L7 resource. So you can make use of a plain [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/) Service. Since you are running on AWS, you can either use an [ELB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/load-balancer-types.html#clb) or an [NLB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html). Make sure you use the right annotation on your Service, for example for an [NLB](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#aws-nlb-support):

```yaml
    metadata:
      name: my-service
      annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
```